# Set FPS in opencv 3.x

Tags: python, opencv

How can i set framerate to 60 fps in opencv3

When i start my program it has only 30fps
(i get framerate from this function cv.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
My code :

```
cv = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
While True:
            frame = cv.read
            #something here
```

Comment: Try `cv.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)`

Comment: @Amogh may i edit my first comment , when i use your code it's still working on 30fps

Comment: What platform and what camera do you have? Does your camera support that frame rate at the resolution you are using? What resolution are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i,m using linux ubuntu , logitech c310 , The resolution that i use is less than 1280x720

Comment: @MarkSetchell i got it ,may be i will change my webcam and try it again

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the FPS setting to work with my camera so I used a time tracker to manage it.

```
import time

fpsLimit = 1 # throttle limit
startTime = time.time()
cv = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
While True:
    frame = cv.read
    nowTime = time.time()
    if (int(nowTime - startTime)) > fpsLimit:
        # do other cv2 stuff....
        startTime = time.time() # reset time
```